# Ajax Jquery Laravel form view save button dosen't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

After click button i've got error in console: app.js:16437 POST laravel.swt101.eu/dynamic-field/insert 500 (Internal Server Error)

On this link  laravel.swt101.eu/dynamic-field/insert  i've got
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

I am making dynamic form when you can dynamicly add input fields using button and save the data to db, but have got one problem with this. When i write data in form and press save the button is blocking itself and cursor changes to prohibition sign on it.

This is model for it:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DynamicField extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'PKWIU', 'quantity', 'unit', 'netunit', 'nettotal', 'VATrate', 'grossunit', 'grosstotal'
    ];
}
```

This is controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\DynamicField;
use Validator;

class DynamicFieldController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
     return view('proforms.create');
    }

    function insert(Request $request)
    {
     if($request->ajax())
     {
      $rules = array(
       'name.*'  => 'required',
       'PKWIU.*'  => 'required',
       'quantity.*'  => 'required',
       'unit.*'  => 'required',
       'netunit.*'  => 'required',
       'nettotal.*'  => 'required',
       'VATrate.*'  => 'required',
       'grossunit.*'  => 'required',
       'grosstotal.*'  => 'required',
      );
      $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
      if($error->fails())
      {
       return response()->json([
        'error'  => $error->errors()->all()
       ]);
      }

      $name = $request->name;
      $PKWIU = $request->PKWIU;
      for($count = 0; $count < count($name); $count++)
      {
       $data = array(
        'name' => $name[$count],
        'PKWIU'  => $PKWIU[$count],
        'quantity' => $quantity[$count],
        'unit'  => $unit[$count],
        'netunit' => $netunit[$count],
        'nettotal'  => $nettotal[$count],
        'VATrate' => $VATrate[$count],
        'grossunit'  => $grossunit[$count],
        'grosstotal' => $grosstotal[$count],
        
       );
       $insert_data[] = $data; 
      }

      DynamicField::insert($insert_data);
      return response()->json([
       'success'  => 'Data Added successfully.'
      ]);
     }
    }
}
```

This is migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDynamicField extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('dynamic_fields', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('PKWIU')->nullable();
            $table->string('quantity')->nullable();
            $table->string('unit')->nullable();
            $table->string('netunit')->nullable();
            $table->string('nettotal')->nullable();
            $table->string('VATrate')->nullable();
            $table->string('grossunit')->nullable();
            $table->string('grosstotal')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->time('deleted_at')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('dynamic_fields');
    }
}
```

This is routes for it:

```
Route::get('dynamic-field', 'DynamicFieldController@index');
Route::post('dynamic-field/insert', 'DynamicFieldController@insert')->name('dynamic-field.insert');
```

This is view with not working button and whitch not sending data from second form, this form at the bottom of the page.
Code for it is after a large gap at the bottom:

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Laravel 5.8 - DataTables Server Side Processing using Ajax</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>




 <div id="top" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 20px;">


 @extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Dodaj nową proformę</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('proforms.index') }}">Wstecz</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif


    <form action="{{ route('proforms.store') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf


         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Data wystawienia:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="proformdate"  class="form-control" placeholder="Data wystawienia">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Kontrahent:</strong>
                                        <br>
                    <select class="form-controll" name="user_id">
                            @foreach($users as $user)
                            <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->showname}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Waluta:</strong>
                                        <br>
                    <select class="form-controll" name="currency_id">
                            @foreach($currencys as $currency)
                            <option value="{{$currency->id}}">{{$currency->currency}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Forma płatności:</strong>
                                        <br>
                    <select class="form-controll" name="form_id">
                            @foreach($forms as $form)
                            <option value="{{$form->id}}">{{$form->form}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Data sprzedaży:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="selldate" class="form-control" placeholder="Kategoria">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Termin płatności:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="paymentdate"  class="form-control" placeholder="Termin płatności">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Forma płatności:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="paymentmethod" class="form-control" placeholder="Forma płatności">
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Miejsce wystawienia:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" placeholder="Forma płatności">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Status:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="status" class="form-control" placeholder="Status">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Uwagi:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="comments" class="form-control" placeholder="Uwagi">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left" style="margin: 35px;">
                <h3>Pozycje faktury</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Nazwa towaru lub usługi:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="name"  class="form-control" placeholder="Data wystawienia">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>PKWiU:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="PKWIU" class="form-control" placeholder="Kontrahent">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Ilość:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Kategoria">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Jednostka:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="unit"  class="form-control" placeholder="Termin płatności">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Cena netto jednostki:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="netunit" class="form-control" placeholder="Forma płatności">
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Netto razem:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="nettotal" class="form-control" placeholder="Forma płatności">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Stawka VAT:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="VATrate" class="form-control" placeholder="Status">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Brutto jednostka:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="grossunit" class="form-control" placeholder="Uwagi">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Brutto razem:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="grosstotal" class="form-control" placeholder="Uwagi">
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Zapisz</button>
            </div>
        </div>


    </form>

<p class="text-center text-primary"><small>Artplus 2020</small></p>



</div>


 

   
   
   <div class="table-responsive">
                <form method="post" id="dynamic_form">
                 <span id="result"></span>
                 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="user_table">
               <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="10%">Nazwa towaru lub usługi</th>
                    <th width="10%">PKWiU</th>
                    <th width="10%">Ilość</th>
                    <th width="10%">Jednostka</th>
                    <th width="10%">Cena netto</th>
                    <th width="10%">Netto razem</th>
                    <th width="10%">Stawka VAT</th>
                    <th width="10%">Brutto jednostka</th>
                    <th width="10%">Brutto razem</th>
                    <th width="10%">Action</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>

               </tbody>
               <tfoot>
                <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                  @csrf
                  <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
                 </td>
                </tr>
               </tfoot>
           </table>
                </form>
                @endsection   
   </div>
  
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 var count = 1;

 dynamic_field(count);

 function dynamic_field(number)
 {
  html = '<tr>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="PKWIU[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="unit[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="netunit[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="nettotal[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="VATrate[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="grossunit[]" class="form-control" /></td>';        
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="grosstotal[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        if(number > 1)
        {
            html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="" class="btn btn-danger remove">Remove</button></td></tr>';
            $('tbody').append(html);
        }
        else
        {   
            html += '<td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add</button></td></tr>';
            $('tbody').html(html);
        }
 }

 $(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
  count++;
  dynamic_field(count);
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  count--;
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
 });

 $('#dynamic_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'{{ route("dynamic-field.insert") }}',
            method:'post',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            dataType:'json',
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#save').attr('disabled','disabled');
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data.error)
                {
                    var error_html = '';
                    for(var count = 0; count < data.error.length; count++)
                    {
                        error_html += '<p>'+data.error[count]+'</p>';
                    }
                    $('#result').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error_html+'</div>');
                }
                else
                {
                    dynamic_field(1);
                    $('#result').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data.success+'</div>');
                }
                $('#save').attr('disabled', false);
            }
        })
 });

});
</script>
```

Comment: You must include the csrf token in your ajax call https://stackoverflow.com/a/41867849/4968657

Comment: What's the response from the server after you click the button? Look at your browser developer tools (usually button f12 - tab network)

Comment: F12 console shows only: 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://laravel.swt101.eu/js/popper.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: After click button i've got: 
app.js:16437 POST http://laravel.swt101.eu/dynamic-field/insert 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: On this link  laravel.swt101.eu/dynamic-field/insert  i've got 
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to define variables in controller. After that changes button works.

```
      $name = $request->name;
      $PKWIU = $request->PKWIU;
      $quantity = $request->quantity;
      $unit = $request->unit;
      $netunit = $request->netunit;
      $nettotal = $request->nettotal;
      $VATrate = $request->VATrate;
      $grossunit = $request->grossunit;
      $grosstotal = $request->grosstotal;
```